# Etemenanki not available in single player

Tags: civilization-6

We were playing a game of Civ VI with friends the other day, and one of us managed to get the new Etemenanki wonder added in a recent update.

I found it sufficiently broken so I tried to test it in a single-player world, but I can't the building anywhere. I know you need the writing tech to be able to build it, but the wonder isn't listed as a benefit of the tech.

None of us have the New Frontiers DLC by the way, I've checked. But as far as the [Wiki says](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Portugal_Pack_(Civ6)), the DLC is not required for this update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wiki is correct, however, you are interpreting it wrong. The DLC is not needed to get the game update which is released along the new DLC, but the update will not give you access to the DLC.

If you look at the release notes, the free game update's features are grouped under **Free Game Update** in the [patch notes](https://forums.civfanatics.com/resources/patch-notes-portugal-pack-march-2021.28813/).

Comment: Oh you're right. But that still doesn't explain how we were able to play with the DLC enabled in multiplayer

Comment: I am unfamiliar with most things MP but it could be that the player hosting the game can select any DLC and you will simply load the assets without them being able to use them. That is, you can see the wonder but can't actually build it. But I would find that strange and unbalanced to be honest.

Comment: We were able to research and build the building. I have a feeling this is a bug with the new update that enables the DLC for multiplayer users, since we also noticed that honey was a luxury resource available. I'll mark this as the correct answer since it has been quite helpful